# ddev nfs mount fails on win10

Tags: windows, nfs, ddev

I get the following Error when trying to get ddev running with nfs-mounts on win10

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: error while
 mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-drupal8_nfsmount/_data': error while 
mounting volume with options:
 type='nfs' device=':/D/seu/source/drupal8prototyp_' o='addr=host.docker.internal,hard,
nolock,rw': connection refused
```

I have checked the Windows Defender FW and added the following lines to the nfs_exports.txt file

[image]

Any hints on that topic?

Comment: Your third line looks.like it would create an overlap, C and D are all you need. You don't mention whether you already went through the troubleshooting suggestions in the docs... https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/performance/#windows-specific-nfs-debugging

Comment: I have checked it again and it looks like the service is paused but no useful error in the logs. Running `winnfsd -id 1000 1000 -log off -pathFile I:/.ddev/nfs_exports.txt` from command line lets ddev successfully mount the project directory

Comment: I now moved the nfs_exports.txt file over to d:/seu/ddev cause I:.ddev is on a network drive. Maybe this interferes with services. The service is now running and nfs mount looks good

Comment: Yay, thanks, glad you got it going.. if you don't think this question will be of use to others please delete it. Network drives never work with docker mouts but maybe that's not clear enough in the docs.